# Run second jQuery click function after first is complete

Tags: jquery, html

I have a number of buttons on a page with specific data-attributes. I'm using jQuery to dynamically retrieve the data associated with the button  the user clicks.

I'm also dynamically adding this attribute value to the final "proceed to payment" button.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#mentor-choose .button').click(function () {

     var mentor = $(this).data('mentor');
     console.log(mentor);

     $('#mentor-final .summary').attr('data-mentor', mentor);

    });

    $('#mentor-package .button').click(function () {

     var package = $(this).data('package');
     console.log(package);

     $('#mentor-final .summary').attr('data-package', package);

    });
    
    
    
    $('.button').click(function () {

  if ( $('#mentor-final .summary').data('mentor') === 'john-smith' && $('#mentor-final .summary').data('package') === 'express' ) {

      console.log('John Smith - express');

  } else if ( $('#mentor-final .summary').data('mentor') === 'john-smith' && $('#mentor-final .summary').data('package') === 'growth' ) {

      console.log('John Smith - growth');

  } else if ( $('#mentor-final .summary').data('mentor') === 'john-smith' && $('#mentor-final .summary').data('package') === 'mentor' ) {

   console.log('John Smith - mentor');

  } else if ( $('#mentor-final .summary').data('mentor') === 'john-smith' && $('#mentor-final .summary').data('package') === 'advanced' ) {

      console.log('John Smith - advanced');

  }

 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mentor-choose">

 <a href="#" class="button green" data-mentor="john-smith">Select John Smith</a>
 
 <a href="#" class="button green" data-mentor="jane-doe">Select Jane Doe</a>

</div>

<div id="mentor-package">

 <a href="#" class="button green" data-package="express">Select Express</a>

 <a href="#" class="button green" data-package="growth">Select Growth</a>

 <a href="#" class="button green" data-package="mentor">Select Mentor</a>

 <a href="#" class="button green" data-package="advanced">Select Advanced</a>


</div>

<div id="mentor-final">
 
 <a href="#" class="summary button green">Proceed to Payment</a>

</div>
```

I'm then using a separate click function to dynamically adjust the "proceed to payment" href attribute (currently set to simply console.log for debugging), based on a if/else if statement that checks for values of the custom data attributes.

This works the first time round after page load. But if a user clicks a different option (i.e. Mentor after first clicking Growth), the final click function isn't updated.

I assume this is because the second click function needs to wait for the first. I've tried a number of different options including setting a timeout, or changing to an .on() click event.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Keep 2nd elements set disabled, once user clicks on 1st set of element then enable 2nd set. Once user clicks on 2nd set then enable `Proceed to payment`.

Please refer below link, which demo this functionality.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#mentor-package a').addClass("gray-out");
  $('#mentor-final a').addClass("gray-out");


  $('#mentor-choose .button').click(function() {

    var mentor = $(this).data('mentor');
    console.log(mentor);

    $('#mentor-final .summary').attr('data-mentor', mentor);
    $('#mentor-package a').removeClass("gray-out");

  });

  $('#mentor-package .button').click(function() {

    var package = $(this).data('package');
    console.log(package);

    $('#mentor-final .summary').attr('data-package', package);

    $('#mentor-final a').removeClass("gray-out");

  });



  $('.button').click(function() {

    if ($('#mentor-final .summary').data('mentor') === 'john-smith' && $('#mentor-final .summary').data('package') === 'express') {

      console.log('John Smith - express');

    } else if ($('#mentor-final .summary').data('mentor') === 'john-smith' && $('#mentor-final .summary').data('package') === 'growth') {

      console.log('John Smith - growth');

    } else if ($('#mentor-final .summary').data('mentor') === 'john-smith' && $('#mentor-final .summary').data('package') === 'mentor') {

      console.log('John Smith - mentor');

    } else if ($('#mentor-final .summary').data('mentor') === 'john-smith' && $('#mentor-final .summary').data('package') === 'advanced') {

      console.log('John Smith - advanced');

    }

  });

});
```

```css
#mentor-choose {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#mentor-package {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.gray-out {
  color: grey;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mentor-choose">

  <a href="#" class="button green" data-mentor="john-smith">Select John Smith</a>

  <a href="#" class="button green" data-mentor="jane-doe">Select Jane Doe</a>

</div>

<div id="mentor-package">

  <a href="#" class="button green" data-package="express">Select Express</a>

  <a href="#" class="button green" data-package="growth">Select Growth</a>

  <a href="#" class="button green" data-package="mentor">Select Mentor</a>

  <a href="#" class="button green" data-package="advanced">Select Advanced</a>


</div>

<div id="mentor-final">

  <a href="#" class="summary button green">Proceed to Payment</a>

</div>
```

If this is not what you want, please let me know. I will try to give your expected use case pass.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't follow everything in the question, the following demo uses an object to store the selected values of the `data-*` attributes.

### Demo

```js
$(function() {
  var config = new Map([
    ['mentor', null],
    ['profile', null],
    ['image', null],
    ['package', null],
    ['payment', 0],
    ['url', null]
  ]);

  function view(config) {
    for (let [key, value] of config) {
      if (key === undefined) {
        break;
      }
      console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }
  }

  $('.mentor').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.mentor').each(function() {
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    });
    $(this).removeClass('disabled');

    var mentor = $(this).data('mentor');
    var profile = $(this).data('profile');
    var image = $(this).data('image');
    config.set('mentor', mentor);
    config.set('profile', profile);
    config.set('image', image);

    $('.image img').attr('src', $(this).data('image'));
    $('.packages').removeClass('disabled');
    $('.final').removeClass('disabled');
    console.log(view(config))
  });

  $('.package').on('click', function() {
    $('.package').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    var package = $(this).data('package');
    var payment = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    config.set('package', package);
    config.set('payment', payment);
    config.set('url', url);

    $('#total').val(`$${payment.toFixed(2)}`);
    $('.summary').attr('href', `${config.get('url')}${config.get('profile')}`);
    console.log(view(config));
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1.25 Consolas;
}

fieldset {
  width: fit-content;
  border-radius: 6px
}

.mentors {
  display: table;
}

.mentors button.button.mentor {
  display: table-cell;
}

figure.image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.image img {
  width: 90px;
  min-height: 90px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px inset grey
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 5px 2.5px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
}

.active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.disabled {
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: default;
}

.summary {
  text-align: center;
}

#total {
  width: 118px;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 65%;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content: '';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class='mentors'>
  <legend>Pick a Mentor</legend>
  <button class="mentor button" data-mentor="john-smith" data-profile='#John%20Smith' data-image='https://www.eikonphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/male-headshot-e1515783468636.jpg'>John Smith</button>
  <button class="mentor button" data-mentor="jane-doe" data-profile='#Jane%20Doe' data-image='https://www.eikonphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/professional-headshots-in-washington-dc-e1473098078630.jpg'>Jane Doe</button>
  <figure class='image'>
    <img src='https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/black.jpg' width='90px' height='90px'>
  </figure>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class='packages disabled'>
  <legend>Select Courses</legend>
  <button class="package button" data-package="express" data-url='https://example.com/exp.html' value='19.99'>Express</button>
  <button class="package button" data-package="growth" data-url='https://example.com/grw.html' value='29.99'>Growth</button>
  <button class="package button" data-package="mentor" data-url='https://example.com/mtr.html' value='49.99'>Mentor</button>
  <button class="package button" data-package="advanced" data-url='https://example.com/adv.html' value='74.99'>Advanced</button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class='final disabled'>
  <a href='#/' class="summary button">Proceed<br>to<br>Payment</a>
  <label>Total: </label>
  <output id='total'></output>
</fieldset>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well! However I still need a conditional statement somehow that checks for the options selected. This is because I have a number of static checkout URL's that I need to use, for example:

- John Smith + Express = https://mywebsite.com/as213214
- John Smith + Growth = https://mywebsite.com/hd2524
- John Smith + Mentor = https://mywebsite.com/mfgh25
- John Smith +Advanced = https://mywebsite.com/dfh23tg

So when the user selects a "mentor" and "package" I need to insert the correct URL into the proceed to payment button. Can I build this into your example somehow?

Comment: @user2766888 Yes definitely. In fact, instead of `config` being an object, you could change it into a Map. Or you can add more properties to the object and add another `data-*` like `data-url="https://mywebsite.com/as213214"`. I wasn't sure if you want the packages combined or only one can be chosen. ATM the packages can be combined, but it appears that only one should be checked since each one has its own url. Let me know and I'll update to show you what to do.

Comment: Thanks! For the packages only one can be selected, so the user first selects their mentor, then a package for this mentor. Each package has a different payment URL depending on what mentor is selected.

Comment: Updated to process only one package. The mentor section has a #hash called `profile`. The `package` section has a url. The last button (really an `<a>` will have a `href` of `url+profile`)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help so far. My only issue is the URLs for the proceed to payment button are very static and don't follow a format, since they're provided by an external system. For example the John Smith + Express URL could https://example.com/abcd1234, but the John Smith + Grow could be https://example.com/zbca2452. So "John Smith" will have a random character URL for each of express/growth/mentor/advanced. Then "Jane Doe" will have her own random character URL's for each of the packages. Can we update the data-url values on the packages depending on what mentor is selected?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible it's just I can't really give you a solid example since I have no idea what or how your particular API is. `data-profile` would be the random variable that needs updating, but it's the API and how you hook into it is how it'll change.